# sbcl - how to input new value for check-type and assert

Tags: common-lisp

I'm excise example from book: ANSI Common Lisp, charpter 14.6 conditions.

But the check-type and assert example doesn't work in sbcl. 
And how can I input new value? it is always failed no matter whatever new value I input.

However, it works in clisp.

example code:

```lisp
(let ((x '(a b c))) (check-type (car x) integer "an integer")  x)


(let ((sandwich '(ham on rye)))
    (assert (eql (car sandwich) 'chicken)
        ((car sandwich))
        "I wanted a ~a sandwich." 'chicken)
    sandwich)
```

In sbcl:
**example 1:**

```lisp
* (let ((x '(a b c))) (check-type (car x) integer "an integer")  x)
; in: LET ((X '(A B C)))
;     (CHECK-TYPE (CAR X) INTEGER "an integer")
; --> DO BLOCK LET TAGBODY TAGBODY SETF 
; ==>
;   (SB-KERNEL:%RPLACA X
;                      (SB-KERNEL:CHECK-TYPE-ERROR '(CAR X) #:G0 'INTEGER
;                                                  "an integer"))
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   Destructive function SB-KERNEL:%RPLACA called on constant data.
;   See also:
;     The ANSI Standard, Special Operator QUOTE
;     The ANSI Standard, Section 3.2.2.3
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 WARNING condition

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {B3E2341}>:
  The value of (CAR X) is A, which is not an integer.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [STORE-VALUE] Supply a new value for (CAR X).
  1: [ABORT      ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-KERNEL:CHECK-TYPE-ERROR (CAR X) A INTEGER "an integer")
0] 0

Type a form to be evaluated: 0

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {B3E2341}>:
  The value of (CAR X) is A, which is not an integer.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [STORE-VALUE] Supply a new value for (CAR X).
  1: [ABORT      ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-KERNEL:CHECK-TYPE-ERROR (CAR X) A INTEGER "an integer")
0]
```

**example2:**

```lisp
* (let ((sandwich '(ham on rye)))
    (assert (eql (car sandwich) 'chicken)
        ((car sandwich))
        "I wanted a ~a sandwich." 'chicken)
    sandwich)
; in: LET ((SANDWICH '(HAM ON RYE)))
;     (ASSERT (EQL (CAR SANDWICH) 'CHICKEN) ((CAR SANDWICH))
;             "I wanted a ~a sandwich." 'CHICKEN)
; --> TAGBODY SETF 
; ==>
;   (SB-KERNEL:%RPLACA SANDWICH
;                      (SB-IMPL::ASSERT-PROMPT '(CAR SANDWICH) (CAR SANDWICH)))
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   Destructive function SB-KERNEL:%RPLACA called on constant data.
;   See also:
;     The ANSI Standard, Special Operator QUOTE
;     The ANSI Standard, Section 3.2.2.3
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 WARNING condition

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {B3E2341}>:
  I wanted a CHICKEN sandwich.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [CONTINUE] Retry assertion with new value for (CAR SANDWICH).
  1: [ABORT   ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-KERNEL:ASSERT-ERROR (EQL (CAR SANDWICH) (QUOTE CHICKEN)) (((CAR SANDWICH) HAM)) ((CAR SANDWICH)) "I wanted a ~a sandwich." CHICKEN)
0] 0

The old value of (CAR SANDWICH) is HAM.
Do you want to supply a new value?  (y or n) y

Type a form to be evaluated:
'chicken

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {B3E2341}>:
  I wanted a CHICKEN sandwich.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [CONTINUE] Retry assertion with new value for (CAR SANDWICH).
  1: [ABORT   ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-KERNEL:ASSERT-ERROR (EQL (CAR SANDWICH) (QUOTE CHICKEN)) (((CAR SANDWICH) HAM)) ((CAR SANDWICH)) "I wanted a ~a sandwich." CHICKEN)
0]
```

But in clisp, it works well.

```lisp
[1]> (let ((x '(a b c))) (check-type (car x) integer "an integer")  x)

*** - The value of (CAR X) should be an integer.
      The value is: A
The following restarts are available:
STORE-VALUE    :R1      Input a new value for (CAR X).
ABORT          :R2      Abort main loop
Break 1 [2]> :R1
New (CAR X)> 99
(99 B C)
[3]> (let ((sandwich '(ham on rye)))
    (assert (eql (car sandwich) 'chicken)
You are in the top-level Read-Eval-Print loop.
Help (abbreviated :h) = this list
Use the usual editing capabilities.
(quit) or (exit) leaves CLISP.
    ((car sandwich))
You are in the top-level Read-Eval-Print loop.
Help (abbreviated :h) = this list
Use the usual editing capabilities.
(quit) or (exit) leaves CLISP.
    "I wanted a ~a sandwich." 'chicken)
    sandwich)

** - Continuable Error
I wanted a CHICKEN sandwich.
If you continue (by typing 'continue'): Input a new value for (CAR SANDWICH).
The following restarts are also available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
Break 1 [4]> continue
New (CAR SANDWICH)> 'chicken
(CHICKEN ON RYE)
[5]>
```

Comment: SBCL won't let you change constant data. see the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to modify literal data. The consequences are undefined in the Common Lisp standard.

This is undefined:

```
(let ((x '(a b c)))
  (setf (car x) 10))
```

This works:

```
(let ((x (list 'a 'b 'c)))
  (setf (car x) 10))
```

Comment: @ömeryılmaz: Common Lisp was designed to allow efficient applications, by possibly using optimizing compilers, using whole program compilers, to very different machine types. The code and its data might reside in ROM or protected memory, where it can't be changed. Data might be shared in different places to safe memory. --- Also important here, the literal list will only be allocated once for the code. Whenever we enter this piece of code, there is likely only one and the same list. When we call LIST, we each time allocate a new list.